# OSError: cannot load library 'gobject-2.0-0': Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'gobject-2.0-0'

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, oserror, saleor, django-weasyprint

While installing saleor, I have encountered with the below issue.

```
OSError: cannot load library 'gobject-2.0-0': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'gobject-2.0-0'
```

I have tried all the solutions given in stack overflow as well as git. Nothing seems to be working.

Can someone please help me out.

```
Tools installed:

python: 3.8 / 3.9
GTK3
```

I have also updated the GTK3\bin in the top of the environment variables as said in the other solutions.

Comment: have you fixed this yet? i am having same problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the https://www.msys2.org/ and install it.
   a) install gtk package and python bundles from MSYS2 terminal. We can start this with command shell. and `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3`

b) `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python-gobject`

2. Update your $XDG_DATA_HOME and  XDG_DATA_DIRS to the installed path for example :
   'C:/msys64/mingw64/share'

Reboot your system and check, it will work.

Comment: What a relief! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another option that worked for me is :

Install  MSYS2 from https://www.msys2.org.

Install GTK3 DLL Dependencies from here : https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases

And then set environment path variables to your windows variable path file.

```
WEASYPRINT_DLL_DIRECTORIES=C:\GTK3\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Python3.9 x64 version.
When I first installed the gtk3-runtime-3.24.31-2022-01-04-ts-win64 application on the server, I was getting the error you mentioned. I restarted the windows server and the application started working fine.
I also granted access permissions for IIS_IUSRS.